# Download a ROS2 package from GitHub and install it with colcon

Tags: ros, ros2, github, colcon

[image: Rosanswers logo]

**Is there a standard way to download a ROS2 package from GitHub and install it with`colcon`?**

I am looking for something more automated than just copy-pasting or using git submodules. I am currently getting away by using CMake `ExternalProject_Add` but I was curious if there was a better way.

Bonus question: what if I want to compile and install only one package in a repository with multiple packages? For example the [`geometry_msgs`](https://github.com/ros2/common_interfaces/tree/humble/geometry_msgs) package in the [`common_interfaces`](https://github.com/ros2/common_interfaces/tree/humble) repository.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/415964/download-a-ros2-package-from-github-and-install-it-with-colcon/) by [LastStarDust](https://answers.ros.org/users/134345/laststardust/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2023-05-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The best way to get code that's indexed is to leverage the tool [`rosinstall_generator` documented here](http://wiki.ros.org/rosinstall_generator)

In general git repositories don't support checking out specific subtrees so we generally don't do partial checkouts, but if you really need to to that you can put COLCON_IGNORE files in checked out packages that you want to skip before you build. There are some other ignore logic available from colcon too.

The output of rosinstall_generator is then typically piped to `vcstool` https://github.com/dirk-thomas/vcstool

The name is based on the previous downstrema tool `rosinstall`.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2023-05-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1